# confused with jquery after() behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is a piece of jquery code that is driving me nuts

```
var count = 0;
    $('#some-element-id').click(function(){
        var currentElement = '#new-div-id-'+count;
        $(currentElement).after($('<div id="new-div-id-'+(++count)+'">Hello World!<span class="delete_me">x</span></div>'));
});

$(".delete_me").click(function () {
  alert('Deleting!');
});
```

Now accordingly when I click on element with id `some-element-id` a new div is inserted and I see the `x` character. But clicking `x` doesn't do any thing. No error. As per http://api.jquery.com/after I can insert elements this way which is working fine. I can ee the new elements in DOM tree using Firebug. Now why no event is fired when I click on `span`? For some unknown reason I am forced to use jQuery 1.3.2 but that should not be a problem.

**Update 1**
I understand that I am trying to bind an even to an element that doesn't exist in the DOM. But please note that even is not *fired*, the event will be fired after the element is embedded in the DOM. I used following code and even it doesn't work

```
$("span.delete_me").live('click',function () {
  alert('Deleting!');
});
```

There is no error on the console.
**Update 2**
Here is the actual rendered code http://jsfiddle.net/8sjcZ/

Comment: the problem is, that the `.delete_me` element doesn't exists in DOM when you want to bind an event to it. use `live()` from jquery

Comment: a simple solution could also be to put `$(".delete_me").click()` as `$('#new-div-id-'+count+' .delete_me').click()` inside `$('#some-element-id').click()` function

Comment: @rabudde, `live()`, doesn't work, please see the update

Comment: strange ,it works for me . can i see your code please ??

Comment: @littletipz, thanks for the help, there was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/vKwm6/

Comment: you will not believe me if I said it didn't work for me. Here is the actual rendered code http://jsfiddle.net/8sjcZ/ along with your code, yours work but mine doesn't. Notice I am using jquery1.3.2

Comment: `$('.delete_feture')` instead of `$('.delete_feature')` (there was an 'a' missing)

Comment: :( bloody hell!!! I am ashamed for this stupid mistake. Thanks a ton for saving my day.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method:

```
$(".delete_me").live("click", function () {
  alert('Deleting!');
});
```

At the time you call the .click method in your post, the "x" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".delete_me").live('click',function () {
  alert('Deleting!');
});
```

your .click() is not working because the .delete_me class is not in DOM at time you call .click() so binding never takes place. .live() ensures that binding takes place for elements which are created at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm you need to do it with `live()`

```
$(".delete_me").live('click',function () {
  alert('Deleting!');
});
```

live() will apply to dynamically added objects

http://api.jquery.com/live/